# Комплексный компонент в битриксе

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте!

Кто-нибудь знает, можно ли сделать на битриксе такое:
в левой части страницы каталог книг с подкатегориями..
и чтобы по нажатию на каталог в контенте страницы отражались все книги по этой категории?
Получается, на странице есть `catalog.list` с разделами,а в контенте - `new.list`.
Как их связать примерно, чтобы логично все показывалось?

Надеюсь на вашу помощь)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нечто подобное делали на обычных аяксах и фильтрах.

Менюшка: (разделы)

```
 категория
    подкатегория
    подкатегория
 категория
    подкатегория
```

По клику сабмитили обычный аякс на url с компонентом который выводил товары нужной категории. Никакой магии с комплексными компонентами..